# Can composer show git progress?

Tags: composer-php

When I use composer to update some of the clones can take extremely long and it's hard to tell what is going on even with the -vvv verbose option enabled.

Is there any way (including somehwat hack-ways) to see the standard git clone output during the composer running?

Comment: Any reason why you don't use [--prefer-dist](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update) instead of cloning ?

Comment: @AlexandruG. I'm using composer to update, I have no direct control over the command that composer users to get repositories (for all I know git may actually be doing --prefer-dist)

Comment: `--prefer-dist` is a switch for composer, not for git. That switch will tell composer that you prefer to download an archive instead of invoking `git clone`. So if you use `--prefer-dist` switch, git will be used only as last option, if composer can't download a zip archive for a particular package.

Answer (score 0):

No, the git progress is not shown, yet. Getting feedback, while loading or cloning repositories is still an open issue - referencing: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/332

You might use Composer's verbose and profile mode, to see what's going on and if something has stalled.

One way of implemeting it, would be to change the git command run by [Composer's GitDownloader](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Downloader/GitDownloader.php#L46). Maybe just inserting some `git` CLI arguments, like `--verbose` and `--progress` is enough. Then, there are also the env variables `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` and `GIT_TRACE=1` to play around with.